# django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: relation "django_site" does not exist

Tags: python, python-3.x, linux, django, postgresql

После того как я перенес локальную версию сайта на другой компьютер, я получаю ошибку следующего характера:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/administrator/Рабочий стол/site_lungscreening/myvenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 85, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
psycopg2.errors.UndefinedTable: relation "django_site" does not exist
LINE 1: ..."django_site"."domain", "django_site"."name" FROM "django_si...
                                                             ^    
The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 31, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/home/administrator/Рабочий стол/site_lungscreening/myvenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 401, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/home/administrator/Рабочий стол/site_lungscreening/myvenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 377, in execute
    django.setup()
  File "/home/administrator/Рабочий стол/site_lungscreening/myvenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 24, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "/home/administrator/Рабочий стол/site_lungscreening/myvenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 114, in populate
    app_config.import_models()
  File "/home/administrator/Рабочий стол/site_lungscreening/myvenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/apps/config.py", line 211, in import_models
    self.models_module = import_module(models_module_name)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1014, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 975, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 671, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 783, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/home/administrator/Рабочий стол/site_lungscreening/lungscreening/users/models.py", line 10, in <module>
    from lungscreening.utils.sent_mail import send_email_for_action
  File "/home/administrator/Рабочий стол/site_lungscreening/lungscreening/utils/sent_mail.py", line 13, in <module>
    one = Site.objects.all()[0]
  File "/home/administrator/Рабочий стол/site_lungscreening/myvenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 324, in __getitem__
    qs._fetch_all()
  File "/home/administrator/Рабочий стол/site_lungscreening/myvenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 1308, in _fetch_all
    self._result_cache = list(self._iterable_class(self))
  File "/home/administrator/Рабочий стол/site_lungscreening/myvenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 53, in __iter__
    results = compiler.execute_sql(chunked_fetch=self.chunked_fetch, chunk_size=self.chunk_size)
  File "/home/administrator/Рабочий стол/site_lungscreening/myvenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 1156, in execute_sql
    cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/home/administrator/Рабочий стол/site_lungscreening/myvenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 99, in execute
    return super().execute(sql, params)
  File "/home/administrator/Рабочий стол/site_lungscreening/myvenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 66, in execute
    return self._execute_with_wrappers(sql, params, many=False, executor=self._execute)
  File "/home/administrator/Рабочий стол/site_lungscreening/myvenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 75, in _execute_with_wrappers
    return executor(sql, params, many, context)
  File "/home/administrator/Рабочий стол/site_lungscreening/myvenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 85, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/home/administrator/Рабочий стол/site_lungscreening/myvenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 90, in __exit__
    raise dj_exc_value.with_traceback(traceback) from exc_value
  File "/home/administrator/Рабочий стол/site_lungscreening/myvenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 85, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: relation "django_site" does not exist
LINE 1: ..."django_site"."domain", "django_site"."name" FROM "django_si...
```

Хотя все прошлые миграции я удалил и создал новую базу данных с таким же названием
Версия Python: 3.8
Версия Django: 3.1.4
Версия Postgres: 12
Установленные приложения :

```
DJANGO_APPS = [
    "django.contrib.auth",
    "django.contrib.contenttypes",
    "django.contrib.sessions",
    "django.contrib.sites",
    "django.contrib.messages",
    "django.contrib.staticfiles",
    # "django.contrib.humanize", # Handy template tags
    "django.contrib.admin",
    "django.forms",
    "corsheaders",
    "rest_framework",
    "rest_framework.authtoken",

]
THIRD_PARTY_APPS = [
    "crispy_forms",
    "allauth",
    "allauth.account",
    "allauth.socialaccount",
    "bootstrapform",
    # "schedule",
]

LOCAL_APPS = [
    "lungscreening.users.apps.UsersConfig",
    "lungscreening.survey.apps.DjangoSurveyAndReportConfig",
    "lungscreening.labeling_upload_manager.apps.LabelingUploadManagerConfig",
    "lungscreening.appointment.apps.AppointmentConfig",
    "lungscreening.schedule.apps.ScheduleConfig",
    "lungscreening.research_results.apps.ResearchResultsConfig",
]
```

Comment: relation "django_site" does not exist... миграции сделали?

Comment: @Jack_oS, Если вы про `python manage.py makemigrations` и `python manage.py migrate`, то да.

Comment: на новом месте имя у БД такое же, как было локально?

Comment: Да, и в settings значения `DATABASES["default"]["USER"] ` и `DATABASES["default"]["PASSWORD"]` присвоил нового пользователя.

Comment: есть GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON DATABASE у пользователя на бд?

Comment: Да есть. Вот какие привилегии были присвоены:  
`create user <user_db_name> with password '<user_db_pass>';`  
`GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON DATABASE <database_name> TO <user_db_name>;`  
`> GRANT ALL ON ALL TABLES IN SCHEMA public to <user_db_name>;
> GRANT ALL ON ALL SEQUENCES IN SCHEMA public to <user_db_name>;
> GRANT ALL ON ALL FUNCTIONS IN SCHEMA public to <user_db_name>;`

Comment: Не знаю как сейчас, но раньше если в пути были русские символы, возможны были различные артефакты, попробуй перенести все в другое место.

Comment: Ошибка могла быть, судя по логу, и с модулем psycopg2  связана, если бы makemigrations не помогло.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Обновил Django до 3.1.5, также в settings в DJANGO_APPS "django.contrib.sites" поднял на первое место и выполнил `python manage.py makemigrations`, после чего всё заработало.